# AES encryption different behavior

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

I have the following code, it's pretty straight forward, however, the code results into different results when running in Spring Tool Suite vs. in Command Prompt. The JDK versions are the same in both environment. I also tried with both Java 8 and 11, but the same symptom. Any insight into what else I should be looking at? It's kinda strange situation for me. Any help with be highly appreciated.

```
public class CryptoUtil
{
    public final static Charset ENCODING = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    public final static String ALGO_AND_PARAMS = "AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING";
    public final static String ENCR_ALGO = "AES";
    public final static String HASH_ALGO = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256";
    public final static int KEYGEN_ITERATIONS = 65536  ;
    public final static int KEYGEN_KEY_SIZE = 256;
    public final static String KEYGEN_SALT = "w4sh3Vzp2ZX6GmPC";
    public final static String KEYGEN_IV = "2QZv3t6OOCLIf6vG";
    
    public static String decrypt(String cyphertext, String password)
        throws Exception
    {

        String plaintext;

        try {

            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(KEYGEN_IV.getBytes(ENCODING));

            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(HASH_ALGO);
            KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), KEYGEN_SALT.getBytes(ENCODING), KEYGEN_ITERATIONS, KEYGEN_KEY_SIZE);
            SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), ENCR_ALGO);

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO_AND_PARAMS);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
            plaintext = new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(cyphertext)));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Error while decrypting " + cyphertext, e);
        }

        return plaintext;
    }

    public static String encrypt(String plaintext, String password)
            throws Exception
    {
        String cyphertext;

        try {

            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(KEYGEN_IV.getBytes(ENCODING));

            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(HASH_ALGO);
            KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), KEYGEN_SALT.getBytes(ENCODING), KEYGEN_ITERATIONS, KEYGEN_KEY_SIZE);
            SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), ENCR_ALGO);

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO_AND_PARAMS);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
            cyphertext = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(cipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes(ENCODING))));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Error while encrypting " + plaintext, e);
        }

        return cyphertext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not the subject of your question, but this code uses the same IV for each message, which is a big no-no. For AES/CBC you typically want to generate a random IV for each message using `SecureRandom`, then send the IV along with the ciphertext (it's common to prepended the IV to the ciphertext).

Comment: In your encrypt method you are doing 'cyphertext = new String(Base64.getEncoder...' - the Base64-encoding already returns a string so it is neccessary AND you don't provide the encoding - maybe Spring is using an other charset here?

Comment: @MichaelFehr: The `encode()` method returns a byte array, it's `encodeToString()` that returns a String, but your point is still valid.

Comment: @dnault: Using a fixed salt also makes the salt worthless.

Comment: I don't see any "command prompt" code to compare this to.